# Lattices in Lie Algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> I am having a little confusion with the different types of lattices involved with Lie algebras.

Root system: represented as euclidian vector arrows. However I have seen the same arrangement with vertices and line segments. I believe this represents the symmetries, or the action of root spaces on eachother? In addition sometimes the 0 root space/cartan is included and sometimes it is not, why? And I assume the Coxeter plane projection is a way of representing the higher dimension "closed segment" root systems as 2D?

Root lattice: a lattice generated by roots.
Weight lattice: a lattice generated by the fudamental weights.

Why are these two lattices represented by finite diagrams when the lattice space is infinite? What is the significance of the root lattice over the weight lattice?

Sorry if this seems like a lot of questions.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: The diagrams that are often associated to root systems are Dynkin diagrams. These are indeed finite (their order is equal to the rank of the Cartan subalgebra as a vector space, which is also the size of a simple root system in the root space) and are actually very rigid, which represents the fact that there are very few families of semisimple complex Lie algebras. I would look up the term online or in some introductory book such as Humphrey's Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory. It's a really cool result.

Comment: As far as the significance of the weight lattice module the root lattice (not the other way around) goes, this quotient is actually two things: the center of the simply connected group associated to the Lie algebra or the fundamental group of the adjoint group of the Lie algebra. In addition, it's order is also the number of miniscule representations of the Lie algeba (representations on whose weight spaces the Weyl group acts transitively.)

Comment: Thank you. I know Dynkin diagrams, but I have seen another diagram that is the actual root system but closed, to create a shape. It seems to show the action of the root spaces on eachother. I was wondering what that was. I have seen it called a root diagram. I think it is related to the coxeter plane. Also what I meant with the root and weight lattices is what is difference between them. Like why show/study one instead of the other.

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh Basically what I am asking is what is the difference between a root system vector diagram and a root diagram? What is the difference between a weight lattice and weight diagram? Why are root lattices shown as finite diagrams when they are infinite, and what is their significance? Thank you for your help.